# Comparing ObjectIDs in Mongoose Query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting, mongoose, objectid

I'm trying to update every document in an expanding Mongo database.

My plan is to start with the youngest, most recently created document and work back from there, one-by-one querying the next oldest document.

The problem is that my Mongoose query is skipping documents that were created in the same second. I thought greater than/less than operators would work on _ids generated in the same second. But though there are 150 documents in the database right now, this function gets from the youngest to the oldest document in only 8 loops.

Here's my Mongoose query within the recursive node loop:

```
function loopThroughDatabase(i, doc, sizeOfDatabase){    
   if (i < sizeOfDatabase) {    
        (function(){
            myMongooseCollection.model(false)
                .find()
                .where("_id")
                .lt(doc._id)
                .sort("id")
                .limit(1)
                .exec(function(err, docs) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                    else {                      
                        updateDocAndSaveToDatabase(docs[0]);     
                        loopThroughDatabase(i + 1, docs[0], sizeOfDatabase); //recursion here    
                    }
                });            
         })();
    }
}

loopThroughDatabase(1, youngestDoc, sizeOfDatabase);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error found.

In the Mongoose query, I was sorting by "id" rather than "_id"

Answer (score 0):

If you read the MongoDB documentation, you will see that it depends on the process in which the item was created http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-objectid, therefore, to guarantee what you need, you need to add a Date stamp to the records and use that instead of the _id

Comment: Thanks! Actually we did have a timestamp in the database already. But timestamps are not automatically indexed in MongoDB. The _id, however, is automatically indexed, based on the time of creation.